# Can Django set permissions on apps instead of models

Tags: django, python-2.7

I want to have authority control over my project. Some users can see some app's entries while others can't. I want to set permissions on apps instead of models, I have searched, but only found how to set permissions on models. So, I want to know how to set permissions on apps.

Comment: use custom decorators add in urls

Comment: Is this for the django admin site? Or some other scenario? What exactly do you think of as "permissions on apps"? The actions that users can have permission to do are typically create/read/update/delete operations, and those are done on models.

Comment: Have you looked into using permission groups, which is part of the default django auth app. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#groups

Comment: In my case, i want some users can see the entry of some app in the menu while others can not.

Answer (score 1):

You can make decorators to selectively allow users to access the page

**Make this decorator**

```
def filter_users(func):

    def checker(request,*args,**kwargs):
         if some_condition: #This condition will tell you whether to allow this perticular user
             return func(request,*args,**kwargs)
         else:
             return render('invalid.html') #return a page telling the user that he is not allowed

    return checker
```

Now just apply this decorator to all the views that you want to prevent 'some' users from accessing.

Ex:

```
@filter_users
def some_view(request):
    #Do Something...
```

Now only allowed users will be able to see the view, rest all will get the invalid page

You can apply this decorator to all the views of the perticular app that you want to restrict access to